# How to target NSNotification for different MPMoviePlayerControllers?

Tags: iphone, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications

I'm trying to create an app that displays a unique info page after different videos play. Currently, I am displaying the info page with the `moviePlayBackDidFinish` notification method but I can't figure out how to customize it for different videos. Here's my code...thanks very much in advance!!

EDIT after subclassing movieplayercontroller...how do I use new property in `NSNotification`?

//subclassed movieplayercontroller
myMovie.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface myMovie: MPMoviePlayerViewController
{
    myMovie *videoPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *movieTitle;

@end
```

myMovie.m

```
#import "myMovie.h"

@interface myMovie ()

@end

@implementation myMovie

@synthesize movieTitle;

@end
```

//main viewcontroller

videoPlayViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import "View2.h"
#import "myMovie.h"

@interface videoPlayViewController : UIViewController


-(IBAction) playMovie;
```

videoPlayViewController.m

```
#import "videoPlayViewController.h"
#import "myMovie.h"

@interface videoPlayViewController ()

@end


@implementation videoPlayViewController


-(void)playMovie
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                         pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"]];

   myMovie *videoPlayer =  [[myMovie alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:videoPlayer.moviePlayer];




   videoPlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    videoPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    videoPlayer.movieTitle = @"sample";
    [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
    [videoPlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];



}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    NSLog(@"Is this working?");

    View2 *second =[[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

    [player.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of MPMoviePlayerController with a property (or many properties) to hold the info that you need when the video ends.  Then, when the video ends, you'll get your customized MPMoviePlayerController in the notification object, and you can inspect the properties to find out whatever it was that you wanted to know about the movie that ended.

Comment: Hi @jsd sorry to sound daft, I'm a complete noob, but how do I get the property (or properties) to hold info? Do I still initialize each player in my main viewcontroller? Do you mind showing me a brief example? Thanks very very much!

Comment: something like @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *movieTitle; then you would say myMoviePlayer.movieTitle=@"some title"; after you create it. once you get the player object back in the notification you just look at notification.object.movieTitle and there's your "some title" again.

Comment: Hi @jsd. I've subclassed MPMoviePlayerController but now the video doesn't play at all. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've edited the code above so you can see it. Thanks so very much for your patience!

Comment: What happens if you remove the property from the subclass definition?  what happens if you switch to subclassing MPMoviePlayerViewController?  Seems odd to me that it would just stop working but I must confess I haven't done much with movie players in a while.

Comment: it still won't work if I remove the property and if I switch to subclassing MPMoviePlayerViewController, then it won't allow the use of the properties like controlStyle etc. :(

Comment: Hi @jsd I finally got the subclassing to work! Could you please show me how to use the new property movieTitle in the NSNotification? I've edited my code above to show the latest. Thank you so so much!

Comment: in playMovie when you create the myMovie object (class name should probably start with a capital letter, that's the convention) you would say myMovieObject.title=@"whatever";  in the didFInish method you'd then just access notification.object.title (you will probably have to cast it to myMovie* to get the compiler to shut up)

Comment: Hi @jsd So currently I've got a line in the myMovie (will capitalize the start letter) object, which is videoPlayer saying: videoPlayer.moviePlayer.movieTitle = @"sample"; so in the didFinish method do I just write something like if(notification.object.movieTitle == @"sample"){do something} ? Right now, it's sending me an error that says "property 'movieTitle' not found on object type id" Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You have to cast notification.object since its declared type is "id" which means "generic object". So, something like `MyMovie *theMovie = (MyMovie*)[notification object]; if ([theMovie.title isEqualToString:@"sample"]) {...}`

Comment: Hi @jsd, Thanks again for your patience! I did all that and got a SIGABRT. The console message reads: VideoPlay[1297:11f03] -[MPMoviePlayerController movieTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d09870
2012-08-08 10:56:10.954 VideoPlay[1297:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MPMoviePlayerController movieTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d09870'. Please help? Thank you so much!

Comment: Figured out another way. Thanks for your help! @jsd!

Comment: In the addNotification call you're using `object:videoPlayer.moviePlayer`.  Change that to just videoPlayer and you'll get the whole object, not just the moviePlayer part of the object.